# Add dynamically item to item group in dxForm angular 2

Tags: devextreme, devextreme-angular

I have a form (dxForm) with several fields and I want to add new fields at the runtime. So I want to find an item of the type of "group" and add to it a collection of items of type "simple" where I can build custom fields from the JSON, Label, Value, EditoType, etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use the JavaScript [push](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) method to add an item to a dxForm collection. For example:

```
<dx-form [formData]="customer" [items]="formItems"></dx-form>

addItem() {
    this.formItems.push({
      itemType: 'group',
      caption: 'Customer',
      colCount: 3,
      items: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'age']
    });
 }
```